# Appending Sequence with Arraylist

Tags: java

I have this problem that I am having trouble with:

Consider the following class:

```
public class MergeSequence{

private ArrayList<Integer> values;
public MergeSequence(){ values = new ArrayList<Integer>();}
public void add(int n) {values.add(n);}
public String toString() { return values.toString(); }
}
```

Add a method

```
public MergeSequence append(MergeSequence other)
```

that creates a new sequence, appending this and the other sequence, without modifying either sequence

For example, if sequence (a) is:  1 4 9 16 
and b is the sequence 9 7 4 9 11
then the call a.append(b) returns the sequence 1 4 9 16 9 7 4 9 11 without modifying a or b.

I do not want the answer to this problem but instead a hint as to how to use the public MergeSequence append method to do this. Any advice would be helpful as I am completely stumped (I am pretty new to java and programming in general).

Comment: can't really help if you haven't shown any attempt

Comment: I think you first have to realise since you mustn't modify a or b you must create a new MergeSequence c for the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this unless you can access the values contained inside a MergeSequence object. There is no method currently defined that allows you to do this. Not even the defined **toString()** method will work because it returns an empty string, which is not useful.

But, assuming you can change the source code so that **values** is no longer **private** but is now **public**, you can do the following.

```
public class MergeSequence
{
    public ArrayList<Integer> values;  // This must be public
    public MergeSequence(){ values = new ArrayList<Integer>();}
    public void add(int n) {values.add(n);}
    public String toString() { return values.toString(); }

    public MergeSequence append(MergeSequence other)
    {
        MergeSequence result = new MergeSequence();  // Create a new result object.

        // Iterate through the "local" ArrayList and add each value to the result
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = values.get(i);
            result.add(j);
        }

        // Now, iterate through the "external" ArrayList and add each value to the result
        for (int i = 0; i < other.values.size(); i++)
        {
            int j = other.values.get(i);
            result.add(j);
        }

        // Then return the result. Neither source ArrayList is modified.
        return result;
    }
}
```